# PHP DateTime - Return specific month

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Trying to understand the DateTime class, but am having problems figuring out how to return the date for the first day of a future month relative to now.

Essentially, I want to return (for example), the first day of next August.  If I use:

```
new DateTime( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of August') ) )
```

it returns 2017-08-01, which has already passed.  I wanted to return 2018-08-01.  Using "first day of next August" doesn't work.  Is there a way to accomplish what I want using the strtotime parser?

Comment: Why dont you set a DateTime object to be for 08-2017 and then just print out the formatted date

Answer (score 0):

new DateTime( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of August +1 year') ) );